# Getting session in block

Tags: magento-1, blocks, session

I set a session using `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setCustomPriceValue($myvalue);` in my frontend `phtml` file.

To get the value I called `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getCustomPriceValue();` in one of my block, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Totals_Shipping`...

But I cant get the value there.

I tried with `Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")` too. But it also fails! :(

Can someone point out why?

Answer (score 2):

the frontend and backend sessions are seperated. So when you login in the backend it's a different session then when visiting the frontend.
Im not sure what you are trying to do here, maybe you can elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

regards

Answer (score 0):

As Sander suggests, admin and frontend sessions are different. If you need it in admin, set it on the admin session:

```
Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setCustomPriceValue($myvalue);
```

Then read it from the admin session too:

```
Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getCustomPriceValue()
```

**This is only possible from backend -> to the backend.**

If you need to have this shared between frontend and backend, this does not sound like a usecase for a session variable. You will need to rely on system variables (Mage::getStoreConfig)